# Running bash script throws syntax error: operand expected

Tags: bash, shell

I have a my `script.sh` file in my project root folder. I have give following urls in an array and checking in as below. I would like to run from my windows 10 > git bash `$ ./script.sh dev`
Throws following error : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[dev]" Could someone please help to resolve the issue.

```
declare -A urls

urls[dev]=https://seltest-eu.example.com
urls[tst]=https://wildtest.example.com


if [[ "$urls"[dev]"" -eq "https://seltest-eu.example.com" ]];
then
  echo "Running test site one"
  request="$(curl ... https://"${urls["$1"]}"...)"

else
    if [[ "$urls"[tst]"" -eq "https://wildtest.example.com" ]];
  then
    echo "Running test site two"
    request="$(curl ... https://"${urls["$2"]}"...)"
  else
    echo "Nothing to run"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: It's `if [[ "${urls[dev]}" = ... ]]` -- the curly braces are not optional, and -eq is only for numbers.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ is sometimes your friend here...